# How to read a Cookie using Symfony 2?

Tags: cakephp, symfony, cookies

I'm building a replacement for a web application the company I work for uses. It was built using CakePHP 1.3, and I'm rewriting it from the ground up using Symfony 2. The two systems will run side by side, with various features being transferred to Symfony 2 and removed from the old CakePHP application.

To avoid confusion with log in details, I want CakePHP to handle the user log in side of things until I'm at a point where I can turn off CakePHP altogether and rely on Symfony 2's security. In the meantime, the CakePHP application generates a cookie with contains a user ID. I want to use this cookie for Symfony as a rudimentary form of security.

However, I'm unable to get Symfony to read or load the cookie that's been created. Here is my code:

```
public function securitytestAction()
{   

    $request = $this->getRequest($_COOKIE);
    $cookie = $request->headers->getCookies('CakeCookie[passport]');

    print_r($cookie);

    return $this->render('InstructorBundle:Default:test.html.twig');
}
```

Using Firebug, the Cookie that CakePHP generates during the login is named 'CakeCookie[passport]'. It isn't encrypted either.

The error I get is this:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::getCookies() in
>   DefaultController.php line 713

What could I do to get this working?

***EDIT***
Cheesemacfly had suggested replacing:

```
$request = $this->getRequest($_COOKIE);
$cookie = $request->headers->getCookies();
```

With just this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest()->cookies->all();
```

I get the following response:

> Array ( [PHPSESSID] => gptbmh61mfkqn6p86d3suhnt13 )

***EDIT 2***
I've been looking at the code that CakePHP used to generate the Cookie, and it wasn't giving the domain for the cookie. I have now fixed it so that the domain is `.domain.org`, so that it can be accessed by subdomains as well.

Now, when I go to the Symfony2 application using Firebug, I can see the Cookie listed along with the other two CakePHP session cookies (which I don't need). The 3 CakePHP domains all use `www.domain.org` even when viewing the subdomain `new.domain.org`, while the one cookie Symfony2 uses displays it's domain name as `new.domain.org`.Symfony2 though still refuses to load the Cookie I want.

Comment: What if you call `$request->headers->getCookies()` with no parameter?

Comment: I get the same error @cheesemacfly, and I will change the Question accordingly sir.

Comment: How about using `$this->getRequest()->cookies->all()`? Or `$this->getRequest()->cookies->get('CakeCookie[passport]')`?

Comment: Edited my answer with the change. Your second suggestion just came back blank. I have checked Firebug and the Cookie is set in the old application.

Comment: Where are each of these two apps (what domain/path) ?

Comment: The old CakePHP app is on it's own domain (domain.org) and the Symfony app is on a subdomain (new.domain.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with help to a friend.

Essentially, the cookie that was being set in CakePHP didn't include a path. To combat this, I added the following PHP code:

```
$value = $someone['User']['id'];
setcookie("passport", $value, time()+1200, "/", ".domain.org");
```

I then checked Symfony2, without changing the code from the previous edit, and Symfony2 can then pick up the cookie.

Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

During each request, Symfony2 will set a global template variable app in both Twig and PHP template engines by default. The app variable is a GlobalVariables instance which will give you access to some application specific variables automatically:

```
app.security - The security context.
app.user - The current user object.
app.request - The request object.
app.session - The session object.
app.environment - The current environment (dev, prod, etc).
app.debug - True if in debug mode. False otherwise.
```

Examples:
In twig: {{ app.request.method }} 
In PHP: echo $app->getRequest()->getMethod() In twig: {{ app.user.username }} 
But for the session object:
In twig: {{ app.session.varname }}
In PHP: // I don't know, do you know how to call it?